# No Cookie Response urllib2 valid credentials

Tags: python, urllib2

Hi I am working on an app for logmein website and I'm positive I'm sending the exact same data as my firefox browser (tested with live http headers ect.)

```
import urllib2

header = {
'User-Agent': 'HIDDEN',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
'Referer': 'https://accounts.logme.in/login.aspx',
'Host': 'accounts.logme.in',
'Cookie': 'csrftoken=HIDDEN',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Content-Length': '182'
}

data ='csrftoken=HIDDEN&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=&email=HIDDEN%40hotmail.com&hiddenEmail=&password=HIDDEN'

print urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://accounts.logme.in/auth.aspx', data, header)).info()
```

Response 
(resp.info()):

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 06 Sep 2016 19:24:07 GMT
Content-Length: 10579
Connection: close
```

As you can see there is no cookie in the response headers

Comment: What sort of status are you getting back? Have you inspected the contents of the returned HTML to see if it contains any useful diagnostic messages?

Comment: the html is the same as if it was an invalid login but ive tried these exact headers  as firefox and even tried new csrf tokens